# Does Toyota Camry V6 (non-hybrid) use the same engine as Toyota Avalon

Tags: engine, camry, avalon, part-interchange

I am thinking of buying a used Toyota Avalon and would like to know if the main systems - engine and transmission are the same or different. I can understand Camry and Avalon having differences that are minor i.e. aspects like styling, options to upgrade, etc.

Would appreciate comments from anyone who is informed on this topic.

Regards,
Ramesh

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year of vehicle are you talking about? While if the same year, the odds it is interchangeable are very high. Once you start having a difference between the two, the odds become less in your favor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As I stated I am thinking of BUYING. The years would be 2014 through 2022. I would like to know if the engines of Avalon and Camry V6 are SAME or different